# SVG. Get paths from text

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, converters

Is it possible to convert SVG text like:

```
<g transform="translate(185 185)">
    <text font-family="'Wednesday'" font-size="40" font-weight="100"
          style="stroke: none;  stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;"
          transform="translate(-78.5 -28.48)">
        <tspan x="0" y="41.1" fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Test text</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

to SVG paths using javascript? To be independent of font availability.

Thank you

Comment: can you please put some line breaks into the SVG to make it readable

Comment: Is the text dynamic? This is something easy to do in Inkscape or Illustrator but with javascript you can only do it if you are using SVG Fonts (and it's not easy).

Comment: The text is written by using Cufon and Fabric.js. The idea is to send font independent data to server.

Comment: Cufon contains glyph path data underneath. But Cufon is deprecated in Fabric in favor of native canvas methods, and native methods don't provide such data.

Comment: @kangax is there way to get glyph path from cufon or maybe another library? I haven't found native way to use external fonts in fabric.js. Btw kangax thank you for such amazing framework.

Comment: Raphael.js [renders](http://raphaeljs.com/fonts.html) text as I need but I don't want to use whole library only for converting. Is there other solutions?

Comment: It looks like Raphael does this via Cufon as well — http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.registerFont

Comment: The glyph path data is in Cufon's .js file - http://fabricjs.com/lib/fonts/Delicious.font.js

Comment: And how to convert that data to SVG paths?

Answer (score 2):

opentype.js can take a font and break it into paths.  It's agnostic to svg or canvas

Comment: I have been using opentype js for converting SVG text to paths and I must say it works pretty well. The only problem I face is the formatting options like bold, italic.

Comment: Does it not do that?  I suppose you could come up with an algorithm.... like for bold, you'd take the tangent ( based on the control points I guess ), and extend it out.. or use svg morphology.  For italic, I suppose you'd do a linear shift (based on the y component) (easier than bold).

Comment: We can use a workaround using separate fonts for bold and italic. For example Arial has separate ttfs for bold and italic.